# Trying to kill process with root user but it says: <kill: (15307): Permission denied>

Tags: django, linux, docker, docker-compose, ubuntu-20.04

I have a shell file <save_intraday.sh> that contains

```
docker-compose exec web python manage.py save_retail_trades_data
```

After executing this python script

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run('./save_intraday.sh', shell=True)
```

some django command in docker container starts running and every things works perfectly.

---

After some time i capture every task pid that is related to command above

with `ps aux | grep save_retail` then im executing `sudo kill -9 <captured pid>` 
The problem is after exeuting  `sudo kill -9 <captured pid>` it says `kill: (15307): Permission denied` (of course 15307 is for demo).

---

**For example**

```
USER PID   %CPU %MEM VSZ    RSS    TTY   STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root 59064 7.5  1.0  351076 130612 pts/0 Ssl+ 10:19   0:05 python manage.py save_retail_trades_data
```

my PID = `59064`
and the command i will execure to kill process = `sudo kill -9 59064`
and the output = `kill: (59064): Permission denied`

---

As long as i know root user is the most privileged user but its says permmission denied,what i thinking is the root user doesn't have permission to kill any process that is running in the docker container.
I will appreciate if you help me to solve this problem

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  Without knowing what this script does it's hard to say more.  You shouldn't normally need to use debugging commands like `docker exec`, and running kill(1) inside a debugging shell seems unusual to me; I'd normally expect a container to have just its main process and nothing more.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks for your suggestion. I added an example to my post